# Merging dataframes without NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I am trying to properly merge two dataframes in pandas together, so that in the end I can have the right indices and columns.

My dataframes look something like this

df1

[image]

df2
[image]
merged_df

The merged_df is simply df1 (the same index, and same word column), except it also has a value column to the right that gives the values for each of the words.

Furthemore, if the word is not in df2, then it'll return an NaN value in the merged_df.

This seems simple enough to do, but I've tried many combinations with the merge method and haven't gotten what I've needed.

Comment: Any code we could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for `map`:

```
s = df1['word'].map(df2.set_index('word')['value'])
merged_df = df1.assign(value=s)
```

You could also create a dictionary of mappings with `.values`, and then call `map`:

```
mapping = dict(df2.values)
merged_df = df1.assign(value=df1['word'].map(mapping))
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked well! Wish I had known about the map method!